# Python type hints, how to avoid cross module hell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

We have two Python3.7+ modules in two folder trees in the same python package.

I would like the two modules to both use type hints to better document how to use the code.

But is is required that the methods in the classes from both those modules use instances of classes from the other module as they link information between each other.

If we do this we want to write something like this.

In module1/file1.py:

```
class A(Base1):
    def x(self, inst : B)
        self.b = inst
        do_stuff_with(self.b)
```

In module2/file2.py

```
class B(Base2):
    def y(self, inst : A):
        self.a = inst
        do_stuff_with(self.a)
```

Doing this means that for the type hints to work both modules need to import each other. And doing that breaks things.

How do we correctly use type hints where the types are defined in another module without actually importing that module?

Or are type hints not possible in this structure?

---

Some more info:

I see there is typing.forwardRef (but it says not to use it)

And according to PEP563 you can use postponed evaluation of annotations

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Or should the type hint be more abstract, e.g. 'object'

Comment: I think you can have something like `if False: from .file1 import A` inside file2. Then use the future import.